# Terms for modern system

Tags: components, terminology

This may not be for this forum, but...

We write new system and people are used to older system where components are called "modules". So they talk about the accounting module and the auditing module, etc...

This feels very old, like cobol/mainframe talk. What would be better term for functional components in a modern-distributed java system? Would you say the accounting component? The accounting service? Not sure. They refer to the function in the system (and all components behind it) that allow you to perform accounting functions.

Answer (score 2):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

The fact that you are asking SO for advice on this suggests that you don't have a better nomenclature ready to use.  Spend your time doing something more productive than fretting about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "module" is a perfectly reasonable way to refer to a set of functionality. It's still widely used in many languages and frameworks. If it sounds "old" it's only because of your own frame of reference.

Besides, the customer is always right. You should be adopting their verbiage instead of trying to force them to use yours. Do what you want internally but stick with "modules" for the customers' sakes.

Answer (score 0):

Python, a thoroughly modern programming language, has "modules." I don't think there is anything archaic about the word.

If users are used to calling things in the old system "modules," then it will make the new system easier to learn if you use the same terminology.

Answer (score 0):

bundle is the new term ;-) ofcourse coined by OSGI. But when you say bundle then lot of assumptions are made on your code. So whether you want to use this or not is left to you.